# Calculating LTV Accurately

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I am trying to calculate the "Average Lifetime Value" of customers. Meaning what is the average total spend of all customers during their time with us & also for a previous 30 day span.

Data in table (customer):

```
|-----------------------|
|   ID   |   FirstName  |
|-----------------------|
    35       John
    84       Mike
    90       Cassie
```

Data in table (tblservice):

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|   serviceID   |   Timing  |  Total  |  customerID |
|---------------------------------------------------|
        1         3/10/2012   5.00          35
        2         3/19/2012   5.00          35
        3         3/20/2012   10.00         35
        4         3/25/2012   10.00         84
        5         4/15/2012   10.00         84
```

note: Tables "customer" & "tblservice" are in a one to many relationship.

This is what I got so far which calculates the average spend each time a customer purchases. BUT I DO NOT need it to calculate the average purchase cost which it does now

I'm trying to calculate the average of **total** spend per customer. So it must total all the purchases made by each customer first, then divide by the total number of customers.

**With the table layout above it would calculate average lifetime value for customer 35 as ((5+5+10)/3) = 6.66 & customer 84 as ((10+10)/2) = 10.00.**

**THEN in order to find average lifetime value for the customer base as a whole, it should average out the results from each customer as: ((6.66+10)/2) = 8.33**

Please help, here are the two queries so far (one for all time and another for the past 30days):

```
SELECT AVG(tblservice.Total) AS LifetimeValue FROM tblservice;

SELECT AVG(tblservice.Total) AS LifetimeValue FROM tblservice
WHERE ((tblservice.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date()));
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add brief samples of data from the two tables, and also show us the results you want based on those samples.

Comment: I've added the data samples and the expected results as well above in the question to clarify it a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate your per-customer averages first, and then average them:

```
select avg(custavg) from (SELECT tblservice.customerid, Avg(tblservice.total) AS custavg FROM tblservice GROUP BY tblservice.customerid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a subquery to get the average per customer:

```
SELECT
    AVG(customer_ltv)
FROM
    (SELECT
        customerID,
        AVG(Total) AS customer_ltv
    FROM
        tblservice
    GROUP BY
        customerID) avgs
```

If you need to filter on time, then add a `WHERE` clause to the inner query.